# C# dynamic method for setting value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method searching for a key in a list:

```
private static void Set<TTarget>(IList<Attributes> source, string key, TTarget target, Action<TTarget, string> setter) { 

    if (source[0].Key == key)
    {
        var value = source.FirstOrDefault();
        setter(target, value.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

however could somebody suggest a way for preventing Set method to set null value if not found in a list? Currently if the Set not found any value then Column1 is set to null, but I would like to prevent Set to set value if not found

```
public async Task Process(MyFile myFile){
   var f = new MyFile();

   Attributes = myFile.AttributesList.ToList();
   // ignore if Set method not found a value
   Set(Attributes, "column1", f, (target, val) => target.Column1 = val); 
}
```

Comment: how about `if(value != null) {  setter(...); }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a simple check, to make sure the value variable is populated before you call the setter method:

```
private static void Set<TTarget>(IList<Attributes> source, string key, TTarget target, Action<TTarget, string> setter) { 

    if (source[0].Key == key)
    {
        var value = source.FirstOrDefault();

        if(value == null || value == ""){
            Console.WriteLine($"No value found for key {key}!");
        } else {
            setter(target, value.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```